# Vaadin 24/SpringBoot 3/Spring Security- REST API auth failure redirects to Vaadin login instead of returning 401-Unauthorized

Tags: spring-security, vaadin

Had a working configuration for Vaadin 23/Spring Boot 2. After updating to Vaadin 24/Spring Boot 3, a failed authentication results in a redirect to the Vaadin login page instead of returning HTTP 401-Unauthorized. A failed API authorization seems to flow through to the Vaadin Security rather than terminating with a 401-Unauthorized. I want all /api requests to be handled by Rest API Config, and everything else handled by Vaadin. My basic Spring Security Config:

```
    //Config for the REST API
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class MyRestApiSecurityConfig  {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .securityMatcher("/api/**")
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
            http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                            .anyRequest()
                            .hasAuthority(AppRoles.API))
                    .httpBasic()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint());
        }
    }
    //Config for Vaadin
    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class MyUIWebSecurity extends VaadinWebSecurity {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            super.configure(http);
            setLoginView(http, LoginView.class);
        }
    }

    public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The rather underwhelming solution was to change RestAuthenticationEntryPoint from:

```
response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized")
```

to

```
response.setStatus(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
```

Now an auth failure for the REST API returns 401 instead of redirecting to the Vaadin login. It is worth noting that the previous method of response.sendError worked in Vaadin 23/Spring Boot 2

Comment: You saved my day